# Finding nearest station to each shop using BallTree

Tags: location, coordinates, distance, haversine

I've got 2 datasets, a list of shops with UK coordinates and train station also, with coordinates.

I'm using BallTree to get the nearest station to each shop with a distance, using a a code from this website and I've swapped in my dataframes appropriately.

https://automating-gis-processes.github.io/site/notebooks/L3/nearest-neighbor-faster.html

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import geopandas as gpd

from sklearn.neighbors import BallTree

df_pocs = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\FLETCHWI\Desktop\XX\shops.csv', encoding = "ISO-8859-1", engine='python')

df_stations = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\FLETCHWI\Desktop\xx\uk_stations.csv', encoding = "ISO-8859-1", engine='python')


gdf_pocs = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    df_pocs, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df_pocs.longitude, df_pocs.latitude))

gdf_stations = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    df_stations, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df_stations.longitude, df_stations.latitude))



def get_nearest(src_points, candidates, k_neighbors=1):
    """Find nearest neighbors for all source points from a set of candidate points"""

    # Create tree from the candidate points
    tree = BallTree(candidates, leaf_size=15, metric='haversine')

    # Find closest points and distances
    distances, indices = tree.query(src_points, k=k_neighbors)

    # Transpose to get distances and indices into arrays
    distances = distances.transpose()
    indices = indices.transpose()

    # Get closest indices and distances (i.e. array at index 0)
    # note: for the second closest points, you would take index 1, etc.
    closest = indices[0]
    closest_dist = distances[0]

    # Return indices and distances
    return (closest, closest_dist)


def nearest_neighbor(left_gdf, right_gdf, return_dist=False):
    """
    For each point in left_gdf, find closest point in right GeoDataFrame and return them.

    NOTICE: Assumes that the input Points are in WGS84 projection (lat/lon).
    """

    left_geom_col = left_gdf.geometry.name
    right_geom_col = right_gdf.geometry.name

    # Ensure that index in right gdf is formed of sequential numbers
    right = right_gdf.copy().reset_index(drop=True)

    # Parse coordinates from points and insert them into a numpy array as RADIANS
    left_radians = np.array(left_gdf[left_geom_col].apply(lambda geom: (geom.x * np.pi / 180, geom.y * np.pi / 180)).to_list())
    right_radians = np.array(right[right_geom_col].apply(lambda geom: (geom.x * np.pi / 180, geom.y * np.pi / 180)).to_list())

    # Find the nearest points
    # -----------------------
    # closest ==> index in right_gdf that corresponds to the closest point
    # dist ==> distance between the nearest neighbors (in meters)

    closest, dist = get_nearest(src_points=left_radians, candidates=right_radians)

    # Return points from right GeoDataFrame that are closest to points in left GeoDataFrame
    closest_points = right.loc[closest]

    # Ensure that the index corresponds the one in left_gdf
    closest_points = closest_points.reset_index(drop=True)

    # Add distance if requested
    if return_dist:
        # Convert to meters from radians
        earth_radius = 6371000  # meters
        closest_points['distance'] = dist * earth_radius

    return closest_points

# Find closest public transport stop for each building and get also the distance based on haversine distance
# Note: haversine distance which is implemented here is a bit slower than using e.g. 'euclidean' metric
# but useful as we get the distance between points in meters
closest_stations = nearest_neighbor(gdf_pocs, gdf_stations, return_dist=True)
```

Upon running the code, it returns the same station for every shop that I have. However I'd like it to find the nearest station for every shop and the distance to it.

Any help appreciated, thanks!

[image]

Comment: Clearly it is a logic flow problem.  If each row of output is expected to be a different "site", then the error appears to be in the loop around site.  Every row shows exactly the same latitude and longitude.   Of course the same station is chosen if you are starting from the same point....

Comment: Double check lat/long, and long/lat order. If 1 of them is in wrong order, you can indeed get results like you describe

Answer (score 1):

I did some testing of the functions and indeed lat/long needs to be reversed for it to work.

Notice the warning:

```
NOTICE: Assumes that the input Points are in WGS84 projection (lat/lon).
```

Hence, when defining the point simple change

```
gdf_pocs = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    df_pocs, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df_pocs.longitude, df_pocs.latitude))

gdf_stations = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    df_stations, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df_stations.longitude, df_stations.latitude))
```

to

```
gdf_pocs = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    df_pocs, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df_pocs.latitude, df_pocs.longitude))

gdf_stations = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    df_stations, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df_stations.latitude, df_stations.longitude))
```