# How to use geopandas to find the nearest value of a coordinate

Tags: python, geopandas

I have a list of coordinates with temperatures at each coordinate. The data frame looks as follows:
eg:

| Lat | Lon | Temperature |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 51.23 | 4.234 | 23.3 |
| 51.29 | 4.211 | 26.4 |
| 51.25 | 4.238 | 24.3 |
| 51.26 | 4.221 | 28.4 |
| 51.30 | 4.244 | 19.3 |
| 51.40 | 4.231 | 20.4 |

Is there a way in geopandas to directly find the observations within 100m distance for every row and create a new column with the mean of nearest observations

eg:

| Lat | Lon | Temperature | Mean Temp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 51.23 | 4.234 | 23.3 | Mean temperature within 100m distance |
| 51.29 | 4.211 | 26.4 | Mean temperature within 100m distance |
| 51.25 | 4.238 | 24.3 | Mean temperature within 100m distance |
| 51.26 | 4.221 | 28.4 | Mean temperature within 100m distance |
| 51.30 | 4.244 | 19.3 | Mean temperature within 100m distance |
| 51.40 | 4.231 | 20.4 | Mean temperature within 100m distance |

Ive tried using nearest_point:

```
def get_nearest_values(row, other_gdf, point_column='geometry', 
value_column="predictions_precipitation_type"):


    # Create an union of the other GeoDataFrame's geometries:
    other_points = other_gdf["geometry"].unary_union

    # Find the nearest points
    nearest_geoms = nearest_points(row[point_column], other_points)

    # Get corresponding values from the other df
    nearest_data = other_gdf.loc[other_gdf["geometry"] == 
    nearest_geoms[1]]

    nearest_value = nearest_data[value_column].values[0]

return nearest_value
```

but it finds the closest observation and its value..
I would like to find all the observations within 100m radius and then find the mean

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find nearest point in other dataframe (WITH A LOT OF DATA)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58893719/find-nearest-point-in-other-dataframe-with-a-lot-of-data)

Comment: Also related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62860141/1025391

Comment: @moooeeeep it does answer my question partially.. as it gives the nearest location for every coordinate.. but my question is.. if there are 10 points in the radius of one coordinate... how to create a column with the mean of those 10 points rather than having just one nearby value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point

s = """Lat  Lon Temperature
51.23   4.234   23.3
51.29   4.211   26.4
51.25   4.238   24.3
51.26   4.221   28.4
51.30   4.244   19.3
51.40   4.231   20.4"""

n = 3 # Columns
data =  [s.split()[i:i + n] for i in range(0, len(s.split()), n)]
df = gpd.pd.DataFrame(data[1:], columns=data[0])

for col in df.columns:
    df[col] = gpd.pd.to_numeric(df[col])

geometry = [Point(xy) for xy in zip(df.Lon, df.Lat)]

gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=geometry)

for index, row in gdf.iterrows():
    buffer = row.geometry.buffer(0.1)
    points_inside_buffer = gdf[gdf.geometry.within(buffer)]
    points_temperatures = points_inside_buffer['Temperature'].tolist()
    mean_temp = sum(points_temperatures)/len(points_temperatures)
    gdf.at[index, "Mean Temp within 100m"] = mean_temp
```